# How to update driver of an existing Ubuntu installation via live usb stick

Tags: boot, 18.04, drivers, live-usb, recovery-mode

For whatever reason, after a reboot of my Ubuntu 18.04 system, neither of my keyboard, mouse and network card was working any longer.  I was not able to login, but the system was not frozen, since time continues at the login screen.
Booting in recovery mode was possible, keyboard was working, but network card doesn't. Thus, repairing or re-installation of the drivers failed.

Next step was to boot from a live stick, which works fine, however I want to use my existing installation.
So the question is how to update or reinstall or repair the basic drivers of my existing system from the ubuntu live stick. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to boot from another kernel by frequently hitting ESC during grub loading and going to Advanced boot menu?

Comment: yes I did, neither the most recent (5.3. for ubuntu) nor the 4.18 worked. However, I fixed it (see next Answer)

Answer (score 1):

The Problem was a faulty entry in the apt-get list. So I fixed this with nano in the recovery mode. Next was to enable the ethernet device, start the networt manager, and reinstall the keyboard input drivers with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all`
After a reboot, keyboard and mouse work well finally.